# How to get all documents in Firebase collection with specific value?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase collection with documents containing info of all posts from users, i am wanting to retrieve all posts from specific user.

Each document has the owners UID, is there a way to query firebase to get all documents in a collection with the ownersUID being the same as the current users UID.

For example something like this.

```
firebase.collection("collectionName").getdocumentswhere("OwnerUID" == user.UID)
```

Which i can then use to display and do what i want with

Cheers in advance!

Comment: Use the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#simple_queries) to learn about query filters.  The fact that you want to filter on current user UID does not change anything about the way that this works - you have to pass the UID to the query as a value to filter on.

Answer (score 1):

You can query all the documents that have the **UID** in its field by using the `where()` method. I'll assume that you're still using the **v8 syntax** of Firebase Firestore as you're using the dot notation. See sample code below:

```
// Create a query against the collection.
var query = firebase.collection("collectionName").where("OwnerUID", "==", user.UID);

// Execute the query
query
.get()
.then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

The above snippet will log all the document fields `OwnerUID` that match with the `user.UID`.

---

For more information, you may checkout this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries).